# Is there something like the CAS Proxy ticket available in SAML?

Tags: proxy, client, single-sign-on, saml, cas

Is there something like the CAS Proxy ticket available in SAML?
I want to make a request to a 3rd Service Provider with the identity of the user, like i can do with CAS Proxy ticket. So the Service Provider thinks the request comes from the user himself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/UPM31/00+-+Delegated+SAML+Authentication

Found the solution - it is called "Delegated SAML Authentication".